# Font of texts changed when images save as SVG in Adobe illustrator

Tags: svg

I create an image with texts in Arial font. then save the image as SVG. Upload SVG to AEM. insert SVG to topic. print topic to PDF. The font of texts are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are normally not embedded with the svg.
An alternative approach would be to use web save fonts like Arial, Verdana, etc.
Or you can read the answer here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg